# Continuous deployment with gitlab, what are the possible methods?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-deployment

I just setup a basic `.gitlab-ci.yml` in order to have continuous deployment on my project, here is it's content :

```
stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh exemple@12.34.56.78 'cd api/dev/ && git checkout dev && git pull && cd doc/ && ./generate_doc.sh'
  only:
  - dev

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh exemple@12.34.56.78 'cd api/prod/ && git checkout master && git pull && docker stop API_prod && docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build -d && cd doc/ && ./generate_doc.sh'
  only:
  - master
```

I would like to know if there is other (better) methods to do the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of answer is expected here, but here is very interesting page on how to use git as deployment tool:

https://gitolite.com/deploy.html